# Signature signed by go code but it can't verify on solidity

Tags: go-ethereum, signature

I used golang to generate a signature, but this signature failed to verify on smart contract.

this is my golang code:

```
func main() {
    pkStr := "fad9c8855b740a0b7ed4c221dbad0f33a83a49cad6b3fe8d5817ac83d38b6a19"
    key, err := crypto.HexToECDSA(pkStr)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // msg: address: 0x96216849c49358B10257cb55b28eA603c874b05E, count: 1
    msgHash, ethHash := packetWithEth("0x96216849c49358B10257cb55b28eA603c874b05E", 1)
    log.Println("msg hash: ", msgHash.Hex())
    log.Println("eth hash: ", ethHash.Hex())
    // msg hash: 0xe11b0baccd047b3912588eb12a9d4ca08a95a5948c82ef212f3e2ee832212517
    // eth hash: 0x86bafec69a7798bdc5d92d5a9219d5dfe17477e6884a90901b8dbacd573d3ec2

    // crypto.en
    signature, err := crypto.Sign(ethHash.Bytes(), key)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    log.Println("sign: ", hexutil.Encode(signature))
    // sign: 0xa8a63707b3ea5a49ca8412b77ff442803c2db8784b756a671df47a4987470d260b58ac4b560ac0ef445411b24ee2b71665da454bd2aa71331a4dcc8ff78270bc00

    // verify
    pubKey, err := crypto.Ecrecover(ethHash.Bytes(), signature)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    publicKeyECDSA, ok := key.Public().(*ecdsa.PublicKey)
    if !ok {
        log.Fatal("get public fail")
    }
    log.Println("verify: ", hexutil.Encode(pubKey) == hexutil.Encode(crypto.FromECDSAPub(publicKeyECDSA)))
    // true

}

func packetWithEth(addr string, id int64) (common.Hash, common.Hash) {
    hash := crypto.Keccak256Hash(
        common.HexToAddress(addr).Bytes(),
        common.LeftPadBytes(big.NewInt(id).Bytes(), 32),
    )

    return hash, crypto.Keccak256Hash(
        []byte("\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32"),
        hash.Bytes(),
    )
}


// ==== output
// msg hash: 0xe11b0baccd047b3912588eb12a9d4ca08a95a5948c82ef212f3e2ee832212517
// eth hash: 0x86bafec69a7798bdc5d92d5a9219d5dfe17477e6884a90901b8dbacd573d3ec2
// sign: 0xa8a63707b3ea5a49ca8412b77ff442803c2db8784b756a671df47a4987470d260b58ac4b560ac0ef445411b24ee2b71665da454bd2aa71331a4dcc8ff78270bc00
// verify: true
```

This is my contract address:
https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xBf987334e0c0180673e2009Fd30390AF160b2CfB#readContract

The verification fails when I use `0xa8a63707b3ea5a49ca8412b77ff442803c2db8784b756a671df47a4987470d260b58ac4b560ac0ef445411b24ee2b71665da454bd2aa71331a4dcc8ff78270bc00` for verification
[image: verify result]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I referenced this [eth_sign_verify](https://gist.github.com/dcb9/385631846097e1f59e3cba3b1d42f3ed#file-eth_sign_verify-go) , and then verified successfully on contract by add this

```
if signature[64] == 0 || signature[64] == 1 {
    signature[64] += 27
}
```

This is the reason:
https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/19751#issuecomment-504900739